# Whonix gateway syslogs question?

Tags: configuration, network-configuration, error, whonix, log

I've been keeping an eye on my whonix gateway logs lately and noticed two things. The first is this:

["Time has been changed" message?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/14928/time-has-been-changed-message)

I am also seeing "Time has been changed" spamming my logs. It happens a dozen times a day for about 20 minutes each time. Should I do something about this? What does it mean?

The second thing is:

```
Jul 05 16:51:21 host Tor[1217]: We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $786926E8C497A6924ED69E23D48B13E92D1E07EE~memcpy at 163.172.67.180. Retrying on a new circuit.
Jul 05 16:51:36 host Tor[1217]: We tried for 15 seconds to connect to '[scrubbed]' using exit $0818DAE0E2DDF795AEDEAC60B15E71901084F281~edwardsnowden1 at 109.163.234.8. Retrying on a new circuit.
Jul 05 16:51:36 host Tor[1217]: Tried for 130 seconds to get a connection to [scrubbed]:443. Giving up.
```

Several dozens of lines like that. Also occures 20+ times a day. Should I be concerned or do anything about it?

I've made no modifications to the gateway or VM settings. I'm using it with Virtualbox in a linux distro. The gateway is completely up to date.

> Distributor ID:   Whonix
>   Description:  Whonix GNU/Linux 8.8 (jessie)
>   Release:  8.8
>   Codename: jessie
>
> Linux host 3.16.0-4-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) i686 GNU/Linux